# Как отключить редирект Devise в Rails после входа пользователя?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

У меня Rails выполняет лишь обработку завпросов от браузера, так как на фронт-енде работает Angular. И редирект поле логина абсолютно не нужен. Как его убрать?